# how to solve if twilio lib install in a directory but not in python path

Tags: python, importerror

I have successfully installed the Twilio library in my Python environment. However, when I attempt to import it using the line from twilio.rest import Client in Visual Studio Code, I encounter the following error: Error Screenshot.

The error message I'm receiving is: "Import 'twilio.rest' could not be resolved (Pylance Report Missing Import)."

I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue. Can anyone help me identify and fix the problem?

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqxmY.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Can you [edit] your question and add details on how you installed the library and which (if any) virtual environment or package manager you are using? A [mcve] would be great.

Comment: Did you select the correct Python interpreter in Visual Studio Code? Or, did you install Twilio in another Python environment than the selected one?